# Port Audio causing Loud Buzzing 50% of Tests

Tags: c++, macos, signal-processing, portaudio

I am in the process of integrating port audio with an existing MacOSX application. Here is my code so far:

```
static int coreAudioCallback( const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
                             unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                             const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                             PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
                             void *userData ){
    /*(V3dAudioListener * pCallingListener = (V3dAudioListener*)userData;
    Aquila::SampleType *out = (Aquila::SampleType*)outputBuffer;
    pCallingListener->updateEQVals(out, framesPerBuffer);*/

    if (statusFlags & paInputOverflow) {
        printf("Input underflow");
    }

    if(statusFlags & paInputOverflow){
        printf("Input overflow");
    }
    if (statusFlags & paOutputUnderflowed) {
        printf("Output underflowed");
    }
    if (statusFlags & paOutputOverflow) {
        printf("Output overflow");
    }
    return 0;
}

void V3dAudioListener::start(){
    PaError error = Pa_Initialize();
    if(error != paNoError){
        throw std::invalid_argument("Failed to initialize port audio.");
    };

    PaStream *stream;
    /* Open an audio I/O stream. */
    error = Pa_OpenDefaultStream( &stream,
                                 0,          /* no input channels */
                                 2,          /* stereo output */
                                 paFloat32,  /* 32 bit floating point output */
                                 _sampleRate,
                                 _framesPerBuffer,        /* frames per buffer, i.e. the number
                                                           of sample frames that PortAudio will
                                                           request from the callback. Many apps
                                                           may want to use
                                                           paFramesPerBufferUnspecified, which
                                                           tells PortAudio to pick the best,
                                                           possibly changing, buffer size.*/
                                 coreAudioCallback, /* this is your callback function */
                                 this); /*This is a pointer that will be passed to
                                         your callback*/
    if( error != paNoError ){
        throw std::invalid_argument("Failed to set up port audio stream.");
    }

    error = Pa_StartStream(stream);
    if( error != paNoError ){
        throw std::invalid_argument("Failed to start port audio stream.");
    }

}

void V3dAudioListener::stop(){
    int error = Pa_Terminate();
    if(error != paNoError){
        throw std::invalid_argument("Failed to terminate port audio.");
    };
}
```

About half of the time the code is run, it generates a loud buzzing sound from the output audio device. The buzzing does not begin or end during each run, but is present or not from the initial launch. What is causing this? Is there a required minimum latency to avoid overflowing a buffer? Placing a sleep(1) in the callback seems to fix the issue unless additional work is done inside the callback.

Other information:
OSX version: 10.11.3
_sampleRate: 44100
_framesPerBuffer: 256

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to increase the _framesPerBuffer value which we pass to the output stream. A value of 1024 allowed for larger latency in the callback, which prevented the buzzing sound.

Comment: Very glad I stumbled on this!  I was using a framesPerBuffer value of 256 because that's what was in the "opening a stream" example in the PortAudio docs (http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/open_default_stream.html). That was *way* too low, I was just getting noise and couldn't figure out why.